# Let $IJ$ be the set of all sums of elements of the form $ij$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

$(15)$ If $I,J$ are ideals of $R$, let $IJ$ be the set of *all sums of elements of the form* $ij$, where $i \in I$ and $j \in J$.  Prove that $IJ$ is an ideal of $R$.

This is a question from *Abstract Algebra*, by Herstein.  I don't quite understand *the set of all sums of elements of the form* $ij$.  Is that suppose to mean $i+j$?  If not, why the word *sums*?

From user input, I have refined my understanding of the set $IJ$ as follows.
$IJ \doteqdot \big\{ \sum_{i} a_{i}b_{i} \colon a_{i} \in I, b_{i} \in J \big\}$

Comment: No, he means the sums. Just the products themselves do not form an ideal.

Comment: See for example http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1208933/29335 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/21440/29335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Herstein wants to define is the least ideal of $R$ which contains all elements of the form $ij$, for $i\in I$ and $j\in J$.

The answer is, of course, *the ideal generated by the set*
$$
X=\{ij:i\in I,j\in J\}
$$
and we want to see how it looks like. In general, the ideal generated by a subset $A$ of $R$ must contain all elements of the form $ras$, for $r,s\in R$ and $a\in A$, and sums thereof. The set of all elements of the form
$$
r_1a_1s_1+r_2a_2s_2+\dots+r_na_ns_n
$$
for $r_k,s_k\in R$ and $a_k\in A$ is clearly an ideal of $R$ and so it is the ideal generated by $A$.

In the case of the set above, we see that
$$
r(ij)s=(ri)(js)
$$
and, since both $I$ and $J$ are ideals, we have, for $i\in I$ and $j\in J$, $ri\in I$ and $js\in J$. Thus the ideal generated by the set $X$ consists of all elements of the form
$$
i_1j_1+i_2j_2+\dots+i_nj_n
$$
for $i_k\in I$ and $j_k\in J$. This is the ideal denoted by $IJ$.

Answer (score 1):

$$IJ=\{i_1j_1+\cdots+i_nj_n:n\in\mathbb N, i_1,\ldots,i_n\in I,j_1,\ldots,j_n\in J\}$$

Comment: How do we know that this is a finite sum?  Also what about $i_{2}j_{1} + i_{1}j_{2}$ or other combinations?

Comment: Well it's defined to be a finite sum.  As far as the subscripts go they are arbitrary.  $i_2j_1+i_1j_2$ would be in $IJ$ but we can rename $j_1$ and $j_2$.  The subscripts are not chosen at the outset, but as they are chosen as part of the sum.

Comment: So is this a correct interpretation?  $IJ = \big\{ \sum_{i} a_{i}b_{i} \colon a_{i} \in I, b_{i} \in J \big\}$.  Is it implicitly defined to be a finite sum?  It does not say that explicitly.

Comment: You can't really talk about infinite sums unless there is a concept of convergence.  In other words a topology.

Comment: beyond the scope of the class? haha...so should I write is as $IJ = \big\{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}b_{i} \colon a_{i} \in I, b_{i} \in J \big\}$ as you did?

Comment: Yes.  The fact that the sums are finite is an assumption which is implicit when deal with an algebraic structure that does not have a corresponding topological structure.

Comment: Well, this notation is actually a little confusing.  Is $n$ fixed or not?  I assume $n$ is allowed to range over the non-negative integers, but it's not clear from the notation above.

Comment: Yes, $n$ is allowed to range over the non-negative integers.  I'll edit my answer.